# Solution for a definite integral of a Meijer G-funtion

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

In an equation, I have an integration which involves Meijer G-function that goes like 
$$\int_0^h t^{-1}\large{G}_{1,3}^{3,0} \left( Bt  \left|
\begin{array}{cc} {g^2}+1 \\ {g^2},\alpha, k \end{array} \right. \right) \ dt $$

Could you, please, provide any relationship that I can solve the above integral?!

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any particular conditions on the parameters?

Comment: The conditions include _$\alpha$_ being a positive parameter, and _k_ is non-negative integer. _B_ is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral can be written as
$$ I=\int_0^1 z^{-1}\large{G}_{1,3}^{3,0} \left( Bhz  \left|
\begin{array}{cc} {g^2}+1 \\ {g^2},\alpha, k \end{array} \right. \right) \,dz$$
Using the Euler transform (see Ederlyi, apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol1.pdf, p. 214 with $\alpha=1, \beta=0$ or [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E6)), it comes
$$I=\large{G}_{2,4}^{3,1} \left( Bh  \left|
\begin{array}{cc} 1,{g^2}+1 \\ {g^2},\alpha, k,0 \end{array} \right. \right) $$

Comment: I thank you, and I understand the second equation. But, the first one, what relation did you use when rewriting the integral intervals from _0_ to _1_ and putting the _h_ inside the _Meijer G-function_ ?!

Comment: Simply substitute $t=hz$.

Comment: I was overthinking, haha. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.